# Facebook iOS SDK - access freshly granted for app

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

Is it possible to determine if the access freshly granted for my app?

I mean : I would like to be able to differentiate between 
- a login that is made by a user who already granted access for my app earlier
and
- a login that is made by a user who just granted access for my app for the first time ever

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions/

```
   if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
 // TODO: publish content.
   } else {
   FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                     fromViewController:self
                                handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //TODO: process error or result.
 }];
}
```